# Contracting subsets

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a (locally finite) metric graph (all of whose edges are length 1). A subset $A \subset X$ is *contracting* if there exists a constant $C \geq 0$ such that the nearest point projection on $A$ of any ball disjoint from $A$ has diameter at most $C$.

> **Question:** Let $A,B \subset X$ be two subsets at finite Hausdorff distance. If $A$ is contracting, is $B$ necessarily contracting?

I proved the answer is yes if $A$ is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $B$, ie. the set of points at distance at most $\epsilon$ from $B$. More generally, my first idea was to suppose by contradiction that $B$ is not contracting, and then to look at what happens in a well-chosen asymptotic cone, but I was not able to conclude.

Comment: should be "has diameter at most $C$"?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define the nearest-point projection? The problem is that the distance from $x$ to $A$ can be realized by several points in $A$. Do you take all of them as the image of $x$ under the projection?

Comment: Yes, for me the nearest-projection of $x$ onto a subspace $A$ is the subset of all points of $A$ which minimize the distance to $x$.